# Is BeginInvoke/EndInvoke good practice for invoking on main thread?

Tags: c#, delegates

Is it good practice to invoke delegate for MainForm thread - this way?:

```
Txt.MainForm.EndInvoke(
Txt.MainForm.BeginInvoke(
    new MethodInvoker(delegate() 
       { // code here }
)));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - because if you're calling `EndInvoke`, that will block until the delegate has completed. If you want that behaviour, just use `Invoke` instead.

To put it another way: if you're trying to do something *other* than blocking until your (presumably UI-modifying) delegate has executed in the UI thread, you should explain what that something is. If there isn't anything else, then `Invoke` will give you simpler code.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make a lot of sense as the code fires up an asynchronous call and then immediately waits for the call to finish. I.e. you end up waiting on the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the thing that other mentioned (I believe this `EndInvoke` - `BeginInvoke` chain is just an example usage of delegate): Using delegates is 100% OK. If this is the only usage of the delegate body, there's no need to define it as a named method. It is cleaner in the code and there's no need to jump through the file. Consider using newer syntax for delegates:

```
new MethodInvoker(() => { // code here })
```